# Calculate numerical directional derivative on triangular element

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Given a triangle with nodes 0, 1, and 2 where each node is located at $r_i = x_i,y_i,z_i$ for $i = 0:2$ and has an associated scalar value $\phi_i$ at the node, how would I evaluate the directional derivative $\nabla_u \phi$ at the centroid of the triangle at the centroid of the triangular element given the direction $u$.

I've figured out how to evaluate $\nabla_u \phi$ on each edge separately but not sure how to get the value at the centroid.

Comment: If its a lagrange element, then the solution is linear inside each triangle.  The gradient of a linear function is constant.  The gradient at the edges is not unique since FEM computes a piecewise linear solution in each element.  How did you compute the edge gradients?

Comment: I just used the values at each node over the distance between the nodes for the edges: $(\phi_1 - \phi_0) / (r_1 - r_0)$

Comment: Use Barycentric coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to fit a linear function a + b x + c y. To find a, b and c solve the system of equations:

a + b*x0 + c*y0 = phi0
a + b*x1 + c*y1 = phi1
a + b*x2 + c*y2 = phi2

If (u1,u2) is the unit vector in the direction u, the the directional derivative is: b*u1 + c*u2

Comment: Thats by intuition. Not a numerical method